# Collecting points game

Tags: algorithm, optimization

There's a 2 players game where you have sequence of numbers for instance: `2 -6 12`. Lets say they are written on cards.

Game take time in turns. Each turn player **is obligated** to take exact one card from begin or end of a sequence (no-skipping). Game ends after last card has been taken. The aim is to finish the game with as high positive score as possible (score is sum of all numbers on cards that player has taken). We also know that both players play using optimum strategy (to maximize their gain). We have to say what score they'll eventually reach.

Any idea how optimal strategy looks like?

My research so far:

```
1-3 cards is trivial
{a}, no choice take a;
{a,b} take max(a,b) reduces to problem {a}
{a,b,c} take max(a,c) reduces to problem {a,b}
4 cards : {a,b,c,d}
if (a + max(c, min(b,d)) > d + max(b, min(a,c)))
    take a;
else
    take d;
```

if I decide to take `a`, my opponent take max(b,d) as 3 cards strategy says, so what I have to do is take maximum from `c` (which is "safe" during opponents turn), and smaller from `b`, `d` cards, because opponent would take bigger one. Twin situation with `d`. But I don't know how to expand (if possible) for n-cards case.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//globals
int[N] cards;
int[N][N] v;  //initialized to 0
int[N][N] sum; // precomputed such that sum(i,j)=cards[i]+...+cards[j]

void updateValue(int i,int j){
    int left=cards[i]+sum(i+1,j)-v(i+1,j);
    int right=cards[j]+sum(i,j-1)-v(i,j-1);
    v[i,j]=max(left,right);
}

void do(){
    for (int d=1;d<N;d++)
        for (int i=0;i<N-d;i++)
            updateValue(i,i+d);  
}
```

The answer will be in values[0,N-1]

One can improve the memory usage by the noticing the following: if we look at v as a big square table, we fill its upper triangular half. For every value of d in the outer loop we fill a *diagonal* that goes from [0,d] to [N-d,N-1]. Now note that while filling this diagonal we only use the values from the last diagonal before that, so we do not really need to hold all the previous values in memory.

Comment: sorry for long inactivity but i've abandoned hope to get an aswer. Anyway let's get to the point: This one seems waaaaaay better than previous one. First of all I have one complaint memory (10^5)^2 = 10^10 which is a bit too high. But I think we can work it out.
sum can be just int[N] over each sum[index] = sum[index-1] + cards[index] and now I can easily get interval (a,b) using one subtraction 1 to b - 1 to a gives (a,b)

but no idea how to reduce v (values?)
could you describe (some comments and stick to names you used previously because it's bit confusing) algorithm a bit more.

Comment: also i would appreciate if you tell me what you do with left right in updateValue, because they do not have sense to me but in fact I have a hunch it may work.

Comment: That's it I assume. Thank you very much for work you have done.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight remembers me of the Knackpack problem but then I realized that is a recursive problem. Are you familiar with OCaml? The way to think about this problem is in terms of a 'set of functions'.

You need to start from the basic case and define the basic functions:

```
e.g. f1(a) -> a
     f2(x, y ) -> max(x,y)
     f3(x, y, z) -> max(f(x,y),z)
```

And then you need to define the more complex cases like the following:

```
if (a + max(c, min(b,d)) > d + max(b, min(a,c)))
    take a;
else
    take d;
```

This looks like a 4 input function, where you use max and min previously defined.
Something like this:

```
f2 (a, b,c, d) -> if (a + max(c, min(b,d)) > d + max(b, min(a,c))) then true, else false
f3(a, b,c, d) -> if(f2(a,b,c,d) then a else d
```

You need to define your "basic" functions f2, f3 and others if you need and then substitute the input values with outputs of other functions.

I understand this is not a solution but hope is a good enough hint to start reasoning in a recursive way.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work:

```
int[] cards;

int low = 0;
int high = cards.length - 1;

int bestScore(int low, int high)
{
  if (low > high)
    return 0;

  // our best score is our immediate score minus the opponents best response
  int lowScore = cards[low] - bestScore(low + 1, high);
  int highScore = cards[high] - bestScore(low, high - 1);

  if (lowScore >= highScore)
    return lowScore;
  else
    return highScore;
}

int bestMove(int low, int high)
{
  int lowScore = cards[low] - bestScore(low + 1, high);
  int highScore = cards[high] - bestScore(low, high - 1);

  if (lowScore >= highScore)
    return low;
  else
    return high;
}
```

Comment: It's from Brasil ICPC to be honest. And for me it seems to be dynamic programming problem. Set is up to 10,000 cards. Which if I understand your recursive algorithm would take more time than universe life-time. It's very similar to Fibonacci recursive computing (two recursive calls). What I haven't stated (omitted unintentionally)  is that card number is even (if it helps somehow)

Comment: Yes, for 10,000 cards this approach would take forever squared :) You could limit your search depth, though, to something reasonable e.g. 20 or have some other limitation based on known run-time and probably get a better response than at least a human opponent.

Comment: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=12&page=show_contest&contest=305

It's problem C Cards
definitely has to be the way in 3 seconds for several test cases. Well I hope someone ever find out this topic to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in case the sequence's length is even:

The first player always has a strategy that does not loose. The key observation is that the first player can collect all the numbers in the even places if he wants to, and he can collect all the numbers in the odd places if he want to. So he just needs to check beforehand which sum is bigger:

If the sequence is {x_1, x_2, ...,x_n} where n=2k

Compute: A=x_1+x_3_...x_2k-1 and B=x_2+x_4+...+x_2k

If A>=B, start by picking x_2k and whatever the opponent does, the first player can always pick x_2i for some i. If A< B, start by picking x_1 and  whatever the opponent does, the first player can always pick x_2i+1 for some i.

Comment: You are wrong. Let the sequence {a,b,c,d} be as follow {20, -5, 20, 44} then a+c = 20 + 20 = 40 > 39 = 44 - 5 = b+d. Assuming you start from taking 20. Then opponent took 44 you took 20, opponent took -5.
You gain is 40, op is 39. Using human brain I can perform better strategy: I take 44, op take 20 I take 20, op take -5. Result: I have 64 while opponent have just 15.

Comment: Moreover this is not answer for my question either, because whatever opponent does is quite important he will try to do moves to increase his score (even if he do it greedy - assuming it will be best strategy while whole game is upon first player). Still it is better sometimes take smaller sum because later on I still have chance to take smaller number from enemy pair as my first post case #4 states.

Comment: @kostek  I was under the assumption that 'winner takes all', that is, as long as your score is bigger than the opponent's, you win.

Comment: It's not an answer (i.e. it's not a solver for n-many cards), but it's true that player 1 can always win if there are an even number of cards. If there are an *odd* number of cards, then player 1 will get an extra card (else the last card will be ignored?), and the outcome will be strategy-wise uninteresting: either player 2's strategy is irrelevant/impotent, or (in the case of an odd number of cards), the outcome is fixed.